# Mock static methods from multiple class using PowerMock

Tags: java, junit4, powermock

I know how to mock static methods from a class using PowerMock.
But I want to mock static methods from multiple classes in a test class using JUnit and PowerMock.

Can anyone tell me is it possible to do this and how to do it?

Comment: You just do it in the same way you mock methods from single classes. Where are you stuck?

Comment: When using powermock, you need to add this annotation to the test class @PrepareForTest(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class). But we cannot specify multiple annotations. So how to do it?

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Just do `@PrepareForTest({Class1.class,Class2.class})` for multiple classes.

Comment: curly braces!  that's what I was missing.

Comment: Also don't forget to switch to PowerMockRunner with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` on the class level

Comment: @NikitaBarishok not always needed. You can define a rule instead to make above work -`@Rule 
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();`

Comment: in kotlin `@PrepareForTest(Class1::class, Class2::class))`

Comment: It is also better to use `@PrepareOnlyThisForTest` instead of `@PrepareForTest`. The latter also modifies superclasses, which is not normally needed.

Comment: But I am getting **java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=test], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=test(aero.tav.tams.task.manager.PMTest)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=aero.tav.tams.task.manager.PMTest,fLeadingIdentifier=test]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@dc9876b
 at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)** when I add a specific class. If I remove the class it is working.

Answer (score 14):

```
@Test
 @PrepareForTest({Class1.class, Class2.class})
 public final void handleScript() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Class1.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Class2.class);
```

etc...

Comment: As for `PowerMock 1.6.5` there are problems using `@PrepareForTest` on method level (only works on class level for me)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using kotlin, the syntax is this

`@PrepareForTest(ClassA::class, ClassB::class)`

Answer (score 2):

**In java with powermock/junit,**  use `@PrepareForTest({})` with as many static classes as you want as array (`{}`).

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({XmlConverterA.class, XmlConverterB.class})
class TransfersServiceExceptionSpec {

}
```

I have used **powermock with in scala/junit,** as scalatest does not have integration with powermock.

```
@RunWith(classOf[PowerMockRunner])
@PrepareForTest(Array(classOf[XmlConverterA], classOf[XmlConverterB]))
class TransfersServiceExceptionSpec {

  @Test
  def test() {
  }
}
```